# A practical reason to use Cross-entropy as a error-function in Neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, information-theory

> Cross-entropy tends to allow errors to change weights even when nodes
>   saturate (which means that their derivatives are asymptotically close
>   to 0.)
>   [Link](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/cs9444/crossentropy.html)

Why is the above statement true? Figures and examples if possible.

Comment: Cross-entropy has nothing to do with neural networks per se (the extract talks about activation functions and nodes). The practical reason to use it is that it is a classification loss, and you might have a classification task. It's basically the divergence between the empirical distribution and the prediction distribution.

Comment: @Emre it mentions "network" and "weights". I was confused if you mean something else.

Comment: Exactly, this page is misleading you into thinking cross-entropy is intrinsically related to neural networks and that it's an "alternative" to the MSE. Only in the sense that classification is an "alternative" to regression. Just forget you read it and get a real book like [AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), or [PRML](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732)

Comment: I understand what cross-entropy is. My question is in the context of neural networks. I don't get what you mean by "classification is an "alternative" to regression".

Comment: You asked the practical reason to use cross entropy and I gave it. If you'd really read those books you'd know that. It has nothing to do with saturation in neural networks.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about why one would cross-entropy opposed to say L2 distance. And, what is the reason behind it.

Comment: You use cross entropy for performing classification and the MSE for performing regression. If you know what you're doing you can use a different statistical divergence for the former and a different L_p norm for the latter but it's still divergences vs. L_p norms. With some tweaking you can use a [squared loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Square_loss) for classification but it does not make much sense; you get an error if the margin is too large in the right direction!

Comment: The question is not regression vs classification. Can you please search/read more before answering. Kindly refer to here: https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/

Comment: If you want to use a cross-entropy loss for your regression task because it has some magical saturation prevention property be my guest. I've been doing this for too long to be swayed by a blog post from the author of  _.NET Test Automation Recipes_. That's it from me; hopefully the next person will provide you the answer you seek. Welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 4):

- During back-propagation training, you want to drive output node values to either 1.0 or 0.0 depending on the target values.
- If you use MSE, the weight adjustment factor (the gradient) contains a term of (output) * (1 – output). As the computed output gets closer and closer to either 0.0 or 1.0 the value of (output) * (1 – output) gets smaller and smaller.
- For example, if output = 0.6 then (output) * (1 – output) = 0.24 but if output is 0.95 then (output) * (1 – output) = 0.0475.
- As the adjustment factor gets smaller and smaller, the change in weights gets smaller and smaller and training can stall out, so to speak.
- But if you use cross-entropy error, the (output) * (1 – output) term goes away (the math is very cool). So, the weight changes don’t get smaller and smaller and so training isn’t s likely to stall out.

Note that this argument assumes you’re doing neural network classification, with *either* softmax output node activation plus [multiclass logloss](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss#Multi-class_Classification), *or* sigmoid output node activation plus [binary  logloss](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss#Binary_Classification).

**Reference:** https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/